# CBC-R when IV unknown

Tags: cbc, padding-oracle

I've read the [CBC-R description from Rizzo & Duong](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/woot10/tech/full_papers/Rizzo.pdf) but am having trouble understanding the sequence of steps that would be taken when the IV is unknown and is not included with the ciphertext.

Suppose I want to send a two-block ciphertext such that block 1 decrypts to garbage and block 2 decrypts to my desired plaintext. Would the following work? If so, why not?

1. Pick a desired plaintext, call this P
2. Create a random block, call this R1
3. Send the random block to a padding oracle decryption routine, call the result D1
4. XOR D1 with P, and make this block 1
5. Use R1 as block 2

Since the IV is unknown the first block becomes garbage, but the during decryption the next block should decrypt R1, yielding D1, then XOR it with my block 1 to get back to my desired plaintext. Am I looking at this correctly?

Side question: I assume plaintext (step 1) should include any padding sequence that the server expects, e.g. PKCS#7. Or should this be somehow applied during step 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. For padding - there's no way to fix it at step 5, you need to make correct padding at step 1.